# Magmi error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory -"

Tags: magento, csv, import, product, magmi

When I try to import some product with an existing .csv in my Magento store Magmi display this error:

> Magmi error: “SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory -”

I don't know from where it comes from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a Magento (or Magmi) error, as a mySQL error.

It would suggest that you are trying to connect to mySQL via a socket which doesn't exist - depending on your Magmi configuration, I'd suggest removing your 'socket' option, and connect using a standard host/port configuration and see if that helps.

If you are already using a standard host/port configuration, then check that your mySQL process is running.

Comment: I did both I tried by a socket and host/port connection. But I'm going to check mySQL process. Thanks